# Hibernate Criteria query with ge operator is getting stuck forever

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am having an issue with hibernate criteria with "ge" operator in my query. My Criteria code is below.Can someone please help on guiding that what is the root cause of this abnormal behavior of criteria.Also to mention my table just has 5 records.

```
 LevelPriority levelPriorirty = (LevelPriority) crit.uniqueResult();
    List<LevelPriority> resList = new ArrayList<>();
    Criteria newcrit = getSess().createCriteria(LevelPriority.class);
    if (levelPriorirty != null) {

        newcrit.add(Restrictions.ge("levelPriority",     levelPriorirty.getLevelPriority()));
        resList = (List<LevelPriority>) newcrit.list();
```

Comment: I can't see any IN Criteria? Why don't you put the ge-Restriction into the crit Criteria in the first line? Maybe you can try newcrit.add( Property.forName("levelPriority").gt(levelPriorirty.getLevelPriority()) )

Comment: Sorry it is ge inside criteria. It's not in operator.

Comment: Also i need to return results which are greater than or equals to a specific priority. so that is why i have to use ge instead of gt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i was able to solve it. I found that i was opening the new session each time the criteria was being created.
So i changed below with the later one.

```
  sessionFactory.openSession();
```

changed to

```
  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```